# Verifying FFS (Find First Set) with Frama-C

Tags: formal-verification, frama-c

I'm trying to verify a software implementation of FFS. The function of FFS is to return the index position (starting with 1) of the least significant bit in a number. I have tried in  many different ways including using ghost variables. Jessie cant verify it and I do not know why? Some pointers would be really helpful. Here is a sample of the code, I assume 8-bit numbers:

```
/*@

requires x >= 0;
assigns x;

behavior zero:
  assumes x == 0;
  ensures \result == 0;

behavior nonzero1:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 1) == 1;
  ensures \result == 1;

behavior nonzero2:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 2;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  ensures \result == 2;

behavior nonzero3:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 4;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  ensures \result == 3;

behavior nonzero4:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 8) == 8;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 0;
  ensures \result == 4;

behavior nonzero5:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 16) == 16;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 0;
  assumes (x & 8) == 0;
  ensures \result == 5;

behavior nonzero6:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 32) == 32;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 0;
  assumes (x & 8) == 0;
  assumes (x & 16) == 0;
  ensures \result == 6;

behavior nonzero7:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 64) == 64;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 0;
  assumes (x & 8) == 0;
  assumes (x & 16) == 0;
  assumes (x & 32) == 0;
  ensures \result == 7;

behavior nonzero8:
  assumes x > 0;
  assumes (x & 128) == 128;
  assumes (x & 1) == 0;
  assumes (x & 2) == 0;
  assumes (x & 4) == 0;
  assumes (x & 8) == 0;
  assumes (x & 16) == 0;
  assumes (x & 32) == 0;
  assumes (x & 64) == 0;
  ensures \result == 8;
*/

int my_ffs(char x) {

  int r = 1;

  if (!(x))
    return 0;

  if (!(x & 0xf)) {
    x >>= 4;
    r += 4;
  }
  if (!(x & 3)) {
    x >>= 2;
    r += 2;
  }
  if (!(x & 1)) {
    x >>= 1;
    r += 1;
  }

  return r;
}
```

Comment: The situation is has not improved to the point where your program could be verified since this question (http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2010-February/001794.html ) and these two answers: http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2010-February/001795.html , http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2010-February/001796.html

Comment: Of the people who can answer your questions, very few (or none) follow the “formal-verification” tag. Please also use the “frama-c” tag.